# How control the "accept" or "cancel" buttons when installing an APK programmatically?

Tags: android, auto-update

I have this function for auto-updating my app (it's a non-market app) and I want to control the "OK" or "Cancel" button when I decide to accept the update or decline the update.

Here is my code (the code works but doesn't control the buttons)

```
public void Update(String apkurl,String versio){
    try {
          URL url = new URL(apkurl);
          HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          c.setRequestMethod("GET");
          c.setDoOutput(true);
          c.connect();

          String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
          File file = new File(PATH);
          file.mkdirs();
          File outputFile = new File(file, "app.apk");
          outputFile.delete();
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

          InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          int len1 = 0;
          while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
              fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
          }
          fos.close();
          is.close();//till here, it works fine - .apk is download to my sdcard in download file

          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
          startActivity(intent);  


      } catch (IOException e) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean you want to control the buttons? the installation happens outside of your app, unless you have, like, a manufacturer certificate

Comment: I want to make a code if accept or other code if decline the app install

Comment: you can use the PackageManager to test the current version of the installed application. You can use a broadcast receiver to be notified in case of update.